# React Datepicker for rendering list is always one day behind

Tags: reactjs, django, datepicker

I am building a ToDoList with React and a Django rest Api but I am also using a Datepicker to render all the tasks for the day by the date created. So if I choose the 12.06 the api calls all the tasks for that day and displays them. But every time I change the date to show the list for the day the list for that day is not shown.
Only if i change it to another day the list of the previous date is shown. For example I choose the 12.06 nothing appears but then switch to the 11.06 the tasks for the 12th are being rendered. If I console log the dates in the Datepicker it shows the right day but if I do it inside the handleDateChange I hangs behind.

```
import 'date-fns'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns'
import{
    MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
    KeyboardTimePicker,
    KeyboardDatePicker
} from '@material-ui/pickers'
import TodoForm from '../ToDo/TodoForm'



function Datepicker() {
    const initialDate = new Date(Date.now())
    const [selectDate, setSelectDate] = useState(
        `${initialDate.getFullYear()}-${initialDate.getMonth()+1}-${initialDate.getDate()}`
    )
    
    
    console.log("In App selected Date = ", selectDate)

    const handleDateChange = (date) =>{
        // setSelectDate(date)
        setSelectDate(`${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}`)
        console.log("TimePicker selected Date = ", selectDate)
    }
    

    return (
        <div>
        <div>
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <Grid container justify='space-around'>
                <KeyboardDatePicker
                    disableToolbar
                    varient='inline'
                    format='MM/dd/yy'
                    margin='normal'
                    id='date-picker'
                    label='Pick your Date'
                    value={selectDate}
                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                    KeyboradButtonProps={{
                        'aris-label': 'change date'
                    }}
                />
            </Grid>
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        </div>
        <div>
           <TodoForm date={selectDate}/> 
        </div>
        </div>
    
        
    )
}

export default Datepicker
```

```
import React, { Component, useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import { apiTaskCreate } from './lookup'
import { ActionBtn } from './buttons'
import TodoList from './TodoList'

function TodoForm(props) {
    const [newTasks, setNewTasks] = useState([])
    const [taskname, SetTaskname] = useState('')
    const [Importants, setImportants] = useState({})
    const [TimeComplete, setTimeComplete] = useState({})
    const date_of_task = props.date


    
    const handleChange = e => {
        SetTaskname(e.target.value)
    }
    
    function onChangeImportants(value){
        setImportants(value.value)
        
    }
    function onChangeTimeComplete(value){
        setTimeComplete(value.value)
    }

    const handleSubmit = e =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        SetTaskname('')
        
        let tempNewTasks = [...newTasks]
        apiTaskCreate(taskname,Importants,TimeComplete,date_of_task,(response, status)=>{
            // console.log(response, status)
            if (status === 201){
                tempNewTasks.unshift(response)
                setNewTasks(tempNewTasks)
              } else {
                console.log(response)
                alert("an error accourd")
              }
        })

        
       
        
    }
    
    const Importants_options = [
        { value: '1', label: 1 },
        { value: '2', label: 2 },
        { value: '3', label: 3 },
        { value: '4', label: 4 },
        { value: '5', label: 5 },
      ]
    const Time_options = [
        { value: '1', label: 30 },
        { value: '2', label: 60 },
        { value: '3', label: 90 },
        { value: '4', label: 120 },
        { value: '5', label: 150 },
        { value: '6', label: 180 },
      ]

    return (
        
        <div className={props.className}>
        <div className='col-11 mb-3'>
          <form className='todo-form mb-3' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type='text' value={taskname} placeholder='Task Name' 
                name='task_name' className='todo-input' onChange={handleChange}></input>
            <Select onChange={onChangeImportants} options={Importants_options} placeholder="Importants Score"/>
            <Select onChange={onChangeTimeComplete} options={Time_options} placeholder="Time to complete"/>
            <button className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
            <ActionBtn action={{type: 'optimize', display:"Optimize"}}/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className='container'>
          <TodoList newTasks={newTasks} {...props}/>
      </div>
    
    
    
    </div>  
        
    )
}

export default TodoForm
```

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { apiTaskList } from './lookup'
import Task from './Task'


function TodoList(props) {
    const [tasksInit, setTasksInit] = useState([])
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])
    const [tasksDidSet, setTasksDidSet] = useState(false)
    // const initialDate = new Date(Date.now())
    
    function join(t, a, s) {
      function format(m) {
          let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', m);
          return f.format(t);
      }
      return a.map(format).join(s);
    }
   
   let a = [{year: 'numeric'},{month: 'numeric'},{day: 'numeric'}];
   const initialDate = join(new Date, a, '-');
   const [date, setDate] = useState(initialDate)
    
    // `${initialDate.getFullYear()}-${initialDate.getMonth()+1}-${initialDate.getDate()}`
    
    
    

    useEffect( () =>{
      const final = [...props.newTasks].concat(tasksInit);
      setTasks(tasks => {
         if (final.length !== tasks.length) {
            return final;
          }
          return tasks
      });
      
      
    }, [props.newTasks, tasksInit])
  
    useEffect(() => {
        if (tasksDidSet === false) {
          const handleTasksListLookup = (response, status) => {
            if (status === 200) {
              setTasksInit(response);
              setDate(props.date);
            }
          }
          apiTaskList("admin", date ,handleTasksListLookup)
        }
    }, [setTasksInit, props.date, tasksDidSet])

    return tasks.map((item, index)=>{
        return <Task task={item} className='d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border bg-white text-dark' key={`${index}-${item.id}`}/>
      })
        
}

export default TodoList;
```

```
import { backendlookup } from "../lookup/lookup";




export function apiTaskCreate(newTask_Name,newImportans_Score,newTime_to_complete,new_date_of_task,callback) {
    backendlookup('POST', 'create',callback, {
      Task_name: newTask_Name,
      Importants_Score: newImportans_Score,
      Time_to_Finish: newTime_to_complete,
      date_of_task: new_date_of_task,
    }) 
}

export function apiTaskList(username,date,callback) {
    let endpoint = 'tasks'
    
    if (date){
        endpoint = `tasks?username=${username}&date=${date}`
    }
    backendlookup('GET', endpoint ,callback)  
}

export function apiPartyActionOptimize(action,callback) {
    backendlookup('POST', 'action-optimize',callback, {action:action})
```

Comment: Consider adding TIMEZONE in django settings

Comment: It's not really about Django it's some how a problem with the rendering from react it also works if i pick a random date.  Like if i go to the 12.04 then it shows the tasks for the date that was clicked before